# Incomplete Beta function $\text{B}_x(\alpha,\beta)$ approximation for large $\alpha,\beta$?

Tags: asymptotics

I need good asymptotic approximations to the incomplete Beta function  $\text{B}_x(\alpha,\beta)$ for large values of $\alpha,\beta$. Specifically, I need approximations valid for the following regimes:

- $\alpha > 100, \beta < 100$
- $\alpha < 100, \beta > 100$
- $\alpha,\beta > 100$